# Is this a virus?  A pop-up box from Drop Box asked about uploading photos from my PC

Tags: virus, dropbox

I refused to do it, and then shortly after, WinPatrol began pestering me to allow an .exe file created around the time of said popup to be on Startup. I kept refusing it, removed it from the WinPatrol Startup list, and uninstalled Drop Box from my computer. Then I got a blue screen - something  about crash dump and since then, can't start normally without getting a Drop Box setup message asking whether I have an account with them yet or not. When I fail to respond, I again get the blue screen and "shut down to protect your PC" message.

I'm thinking that the original pop-up asking about uploading my photos must have come from some malicious source and not Drop Box. Probably no matter what I clicked in it, I would have gotten this problem. If only I had just shut down the computer!

Virus protection has also been disabled in my Symantec business client window and I can't use its live update to fix the problem.

Does anybody know if some cracker/hacker (Sorry, good hackers!) is getting into PCs with a fake message from Drop Box?

Comment: when you say "pop up" do you actually mean "image in a new browser window" in which case when you "refused to do it" did you actually just click on an image of a submit button, and actually accepted the virus ? -- for what it's worth, i'd recommend always using the window "X" top right and not click anything on any pop up at all.

Comment: and also, your machine is very likely infected. - there's good posts on this site about cleaning up infections.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)

Answer (score 5):

Dropbox recently added a new feature to their client for Windows and phones that has a facility to [automatically upload](https://www.dropbox.com/help/287) photos to their cloud for backup and sharing.  You get some extra space as a reward for using the new feature of extra disk space.

This is most likely the cause of the original popup, rather than a hacker or virus.  You haven't listed the .exe that Winpatrol was referring to, but personal firewalls will generally ask you to reconfirm access if an .exe changes, so this was probably just the updated dropbox.exe trying to access the internet to sync.

The uninstall of dropbox failed due to the bluescreen.  A bluescreen can be cause by any number of things, perhaps only indirectly related to dropbox.  Perhaps network drivers or some disk corruption.

Dropbox is asking for the account details because that is what it does when it is not configured.  The uninstall most likely deleted your dropbox account details, but then didn't finish uninstalling.  So the startup service is still running at startup.  If you haven't got a Dropbox entry in your Add/Remove programs, then it may be best to re-install drobbox, then uninstall it, once you get rid of the bluescreen issue.

To confirm whether dropbox is causing the bluescreen, go to Start, then type `msconfig` in the search menu, open `msconfig`, and go to the `Startup` tab.  Look through there and uncheck any dropbox entries (you can also do this from Winpatrol).  Then restart.  If the bluescreen goes away, then you are ok.  If it doesn't then it is something else causing the problem, so updating drivers, and run `chkdsk` on your disks to make sure you don't have any corruption.